# Android: How to modify a WebView created in main activity from another activity

Tags: android, webview

I have created a Webview in my Main Activity and I load the relevant html file. When I hit the settings icon, I launch another activity(SettingsActivity), I want to be able to alter the WebView from the SettingsActivity.

Eg. in my SettingsActivity I would like to change the font size or do whatever to it:

```
MainActivity mActivity= new MainActivity();

mActivity.myWebView.getSettings().setDefaultFontSize(8);
```

In this case I got a null pointer exception. So how do I access/pass the webView data created in my activity to another.

Thanks,
Matt

Comment: you can't touch or modify another activities view from other activity.

Answer (score 0):

In your case you should run `startActivityForResult()` when starting `SettingsActivity` and send bundled changes data via return `Intent` with result. Read official [docs](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html) that cover two-way communication between activities.

Comment: thanks for that, but is there a way to not reload the the mainActivity on return? when using onActivityResult

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by these following Methods:
1. You can use change webView Settings on onActivityResult by starting setting activity as startActivityforResult and pass the result from setting activiy.

2. You can create a ResultReciever and pass the reference to Intent to startActivity and Pass the message from setting activity to MainActivity using Bundle. Please ResultReciever in Android.
3. You can create a static variable or shared preference and consider it as Signal to update webview and made changes as MainActivity again resumed inside onResume method after finishing of SettingActivity.
4. You can register custom Broadcast inside MainActivity and send Broadcast from SettingActivity to Update webView.

Comment: But using a startActivityForResult() to launch my SettingsActivity and to send back the result via setResult and onActivityResult() method will cause the MainActivity to refresh.

Comment: So my main goal out of all this is to change the font size for example on the webview via the SettingsActivity (meaning I would need to alter the WebView) without refreshing the MainActivity so that when you navigate back to the WebView (MainActivity) via a back press the page is where it left off on the html page.